# sql server express 2008 problems

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection

We just recently switched from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010. I have an application which uses sql express database locally. The problem is after installing new Visual Studio, I can't access the Sql Server 2008 express. When I try to create a new database, or change the existing one, I get following message:

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: TCP Provider,
>   Error 0 - No connection could be made
>   because target machine is actively
>   refused it.)

When I check the sqlexpress windows service, it is stopped. If I try to enable it, it runs for a few seconds and then stops again.

Comment: Does the Event Viewer shed any light on the service not starting properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove sql express completly. Then reinstall the latest sql express version

Comment: this worked, but not entirely. I also had to delete directory with sql master table.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the error logs, in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\

There should be files called `ERRORLOG` and `ERRORLOG.X` the latest one should give you an indication why the service failed to start.

*They are plain text files and can be opened in Notepad.*

**Edit** Your error is at the bottom

```
2010-07-20 16:05:59.54 spid7s      Cannot create file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\temp_MS_AgentSigningCertificate_database.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
```

So try renaming the file `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\temp_MS_AgentSigningCertificate_database.mdf` and start the service again.

If it fails, then look in that file (it should be a new one) in Notepad to see if there are any new errors.

Comment: Edited post with further instructions.